# Tablename as variable in DB2 procedure in for loop

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I would like to transform the following script from static sql statement for `FOR` loop in DB2 to a dynamic one. concretly taking the tablename from the procedure parameters and use it in the SQL statement in the `FOR DO` loop.

The starting point is this script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE fullname CHAR(40);

FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT firstnme, midinit, lastname FROM employee
DO 
  SET fullname = v.lastname || ',' || v.firstnme 
                 ||' ' || v.midinit;
  INSERT INTO tnames VALUES (fullname);
END FOR;
END
```

I would like to do something like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P(IN TABLENAME VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'TABLE1')
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE fullname CHAR(40);

FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT firstnme, midinit, lastname FROM TABLENAME 
DO 
  SET fullname = v.lastname || ',' || v.firstnme 
                 ||' ' || v.midinit;
  INSERT INTO tnames VALUES (fullname);
END FOR;
END
```

Is there a way to do this ? I've tried the `STATEMENT` but I can't make it work with `FOR LOOP`.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but you don't need a curser in your initial script.  In fact, I'm not even sure why you need the tnames table.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks for the reply. What is inside the `DO .. END FOR` statement doesn't really matter . I will do something else, I just wanted to keep it simple. The actual problem is doing the same operation on different tables depending on the procedure parameter.

Comment: Are you getting any error or what is the problem??

Comment: @Rams yes It says that TABLENAME is undefined because it looks for a table that is named 'TABLENAME' and not using the content of the variable given as input to the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work without the `FOR LOOP` using this method:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE P(IN TABLENAME VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'TABLE1')
 LANGUAGE SQL
 BEGIN 
    DECLARE fname VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE mdinit VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE lname VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE dumy VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'POP';
    DECLARE stmt STATEMENT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR stmt;

    SET text = 'SELECT firstnme, midinit, lastname FROM ' || TABLENAME;
    PREPARE stmt FROM text; 
    OPEN cur1;
    fetch_loop:
        LOOP FETCH cur1 INTO fname,mdinit,lname; 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'update '|| TABLENAME || ' set midinit=' || dumy || ' where firstname = ' || fname; 
        END LOOP fetch_loop;
    CLOSE cur1;
END
```

But still no solution for the `FOR LOOP`